# How to add annotation in PDF src block like in this screenshot?

Tags: org-mode, latex, pdf

How to write Org-mode, (maybe need use LaTeX) to archive this effect?

[image]

Comment: I was interested in this too, I think one answer is this: http://piotrkosoft.net/pub/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzmark/tikzmark.pdf (see especially section 5.2, after reading about the general idea/usage)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is focused on what I'm interested in, therefore it uses `minted` for source code listings with Org, and `tikzmark` as the package that can "mark" a place in your listing so that you can later refer to it from a Tikz picture. Here's a simple example (UPDATED):

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{minted}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

* Using minted with tikzmark 

# Org mode sample configuration (in your init.el file):
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports none
  (setq org-latex-listings 'minted)
  (setq org-latex-minted-options
        '(("frame" "lines") ("linenos" "true")))
#+END_SRC

#+ATTR_LATEX: :caption \caption{Yes}\label{lst:code}
#+BEGIN_listing 
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options escapeinside=||
#+BEGIN_SRC c
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main()
  {
    // comment 
    printf("hello world\n"); |$\tikzmark{too}$|
    return 0;
  }
#+END_SRC
#+END_listing

#+BEGIN_LaTeX
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[dashed,->] (pic cs:too) ++(0,0.25) to[bend left] 
                 ++(5,-1)node[right]{$\bullet$ Here it is too!};
\end{tikzpicture}
#+END_LaTeX

As you can see in code listing \ref{lst:code}, \ldots
```

... and this is the result (exported to LaTeX - XeLaTeX in my case):

[image]

I edited the original answer to show how to place marks outside comments (using the pygments option "escapeinside", instead of the comment-limited "mathescape" option from the original answer) and how to set up a caption, a label for this environment, and also how to get a reference to it. HTH

---

2ND UPDATE: Here's a version of the same code (same output), that manages to use `#+CAPTION`, `#+LABEL` and `[[lst:ref]]` styles instead of the latex ones, *AND* gets rid of the enveloping listing environment completely:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

* Using minted with tikzmark 

# Org mode configuration:
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports none
  (setq org-latex-listings 'minted)
  (setq org-latex-minted-options
        '(("frame" "lines") ("linenos" "true") ("escapeinside" "||")))
#+END_SRC

#+LABEL: lst:code
#+CAPTION: Yes
#+BEGIN_SRC c
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main()
  {
    // comment 
    printf("hello world\n"); |$\tikzmark{too}$|
    return 0;
  }
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_LaTeX
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \draw[dashed,->] (pic cs:too) ++(0,0.25) to[bend left]
      ++(5,-1)node[right]{$\bullet$ Here it is too!};
    \end{tikzpicture}
#+END_LaTeX

As you can see in [[lst:code]], \ldots
```

This didn't work, until I got rid of the `#+ATTR_LATEX:` line - no matter where I tried to put it, it interfered with the association between caption/label and the source block.